# R script CLI arguments

Tags: r

I am very new to R and trying few things. I am facing an error where i am trying to print the command line arguments with a message. I tried to find some help over the internet but still i am seeing the error

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

cat(args, sep = "\n")
# test if there is at least one argument: if not, return an error
if (length(args) !=1 ) {
  stop("Need data param(YYYYMMDD)", call.=FALSE)
}


ext <- args[1]
print("Running R model for date:", ext)
```

Error

```
Error in args[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Execution halted
```

Comment: How do you call the script?

Comment: Rscript scriptname 20200808

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.. But your error suggests that `args` is a function. For some reason it doesn't see your declaration on the first line. Just for curiosity - can you try rename `args` to something like `argz` ?

Comment: I could also not reproduce. The script throw an error at the print line and demanded to set options digits and quite.

Answer (score 0):

So R is an object oriented language. When you face an error like this, is because you trying to subset (subset means using the square brakects - [] to extract an element of this object) a function. So the object that you trying to subset, is a function, not a character vector of arguments.

In R, we have the base function called args(). So maybe, what is happennig, is that you forgot to create the object "args" before you execute your line code below. When you do not create the args object, the R, search for the bult-in args() function, that is when the error appears.

```
ext <- args[1]
```